# Representation of an indicator variable conditional on means

Tags: summation, economics, means

I am just starting out with math in uni for my research so this is a really simple question. I calculated the fraction of number of school enrollments during a policy period from 1991 to 1993 over the total number of enrollments in the sample period - 1981 to 2001 for each province in my country. I then ranked these values and for those provinces with rates of enrollment during policy period greater than the mean of all provinces, the indicator variable will be equal to one and categorized as a High Intensity Province (PI).

I want to formalize this exercise for my research paper and I would like to know if this is the right way to do it.
$PI_i = \begin{cases}1~&{\text{ if }}\bar x_i >  \Sigma_{i=1}^k \frac{\text{number of enrollments 1991-93}_i}{\text{number of enrollments 1981-2001}_i} \\0~& {\text{other wise.}}\end{cases}\ $

Comment: Flamboyant notation does not necessarily clarify things. Quite the contrary. Is $i$ the index of the province ? What is $\bar{x}_i$ ? Why $>$ ? That $\sum_{i=1}^k$ is a sum over provinces ? It is not an average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ index a province and $t$ index the year (we will index the year 1900 as year "0").

Let $P$ denote the number of provinces in your sample.

Let $s_{p,t}$ denote the number of school enrollments in province $p$ in year $t$.

The fraction of school enrollments for province $p$ in the policy period relative to the sample period is then

$$f_p:={\sum_{t=91}^{93}s_{p,t} \over \sum_{t=81}^{101}s_{p,t}},$$

whose average is

$$f:={1\over P}\sum_{p=1}^P f_p.$$

The indicator for a "high intensity province" is then ${\bf 1}_{f_p>f}.$